# How to see repository path in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, path, repository

Is it possible in Eclipse to see the full repository path associated with a project?

This is a bit trivial information so I would expect it would be available somewhere but I can't find it.

So for Subversion I can of course go to the command line and do svn info but I would expect that this information is also available in Eclipse. This is the most trivial but also the most essential information about a resource.

Answer (score 7):

Right-click on the project or file and click properties.  Then select the "Subversion" section from the left.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have a Subversion plugin installed in Eclipse, right? Otherwise just add one, and everything comes up automatically.

Please have a look at the following preferences afterwards:

- Team -> SVN -> Label decorations: There you can configure what is shown directly besides the project nodes in the project explorer. The available variables to configure what exactly is shown depend on whether you use the Subclipse or the Subversive plugin.
- General -> Appearance -> Label decorations: There you globally enable/disable label decorations.